# Undefined operator '.*' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab

```
for i=1:3
    S=sum(w(i).*srmap{i});
end
```

Code above causes following error:

> Undefined operator '.*' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
>
> Error in test1 (line 23)
> `S=sum(w(i).*srmap{i});`

What is the meaning of this error?

`w(i)` is a number and `srmap{i}` is a matrix.

Comment: You can use `*` to multiply a matrix by scalar. Not need `.*`. About the error, please add the definition of `w` and `sramp`. For example, if your description is exact, it should work: `w=1:5; sramp{1}=rand(4); w(1).*sramp{1}` works well.

Comment: Well, the error message clearly says that one of `w(i)` or `srmap{i}` is a cell. Have you checked their type? Like, `disp(class(w)); disp(class(srmap{i});` or with a breakpoint on the faulty line?

Comment: I have know what is wrong ,it means the type is not match,it can not direct multiply.because the type is not the  same .I need to take out the value in the cell first, and then perform the operation.thanks a lot for  your help.